# No puedo levantar mi proyecto en java( spring mvc)

Tags: java, spring-mvc

estoy trabajando en un proyecto de el instituto  uso java con el framework spring , hoy todo el dia estube trabajando en el proyecto  con normalidad , pero luego de un rato simplemente el proyecto ya no levanta me dice este error

```
In-place deployment at C:\Users\SARA\Desktop\PROYECTOS IDAT\SAT-PRACO-java\SAT-PRACO-spring\build\web
GlassFish Server 4.1.1, deploy, null, false
C:\Users\SARA\Desktop\PROYECTOS IDAT\SAT-PRACO-java\SAT-PRACO-spring\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1054: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Estoy usando el IDE NEdbeans 8.2, el proyecto no levanta ya intente de todo  ya limpie y volvi a construir el proyecto ,ya ejecute nedbeans como administrador, ya comente las lineas que me dan error en el archivo build-impl.xml, simplemente no funciona. Espero puedan ayudarme este proyecto es muy importate para mi nota . GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO. adjunto pantalla de el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ademas en la pestaña de glassfish server me sale esto :

```
Grave:   Exception while loading the app
Grave:   Undeployment failed for context /SAT-PRACO-spring
Grave:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'indexController' bean method 
public java.util.List<SAT.PRACO.MODEL.model_tareaUser> SAT.PRACO.CONTROLLER.indexController.listaTareasPorUser(java.lang.String)
to {[/listaTareasPorUser],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}: There is already 'indexController' bean method
public java.util.List<SAT.PRACO.MODEL.model_tareaUser> SAT.PRACO.CONTROLLER.indexController.listaTareasParaReporte(java.lang.String) mapped.
Información:   visiting unvisited references
```

Comment: Mira el log de Glassfish y pégalo en la pregunta *\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log

Comment: Estás usando ant?

Comment: hola, gracias por sus respuestas acabo de editar la pregunta con un mensaje que sale en la pestaña glassfish server